# Using wpf in forms sides get cut off

Tags: .net, wpf, forms, xaml

I am a newbie to WPF, I am creating a speedometer for a GUI, i elaborated the XAML code from different sites and obtained the following:

[image: screenshot]

Once I include it in the GUI built with forms the sides are cut off. no matter how I modify the margins or the sizes.

I believe I can solve it using row and columns, here it is the code XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GuiTest1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"           
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GuiTest1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
          Height="238.052" Width="288.042">


<Grid Background="#FF2E2F45" Margin="0,0,0.6,0.8">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="238"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="288"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="1.6"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ed:Arc Grid.Row="0" StartAngle="-120" EndAngle="120" Stretch="None" StrokeThickness="18"      
                StrokeDashArray=".25" Stroke="#FF484D5F" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0,1.4" />
    <ed:Arc Grid.Row="0" StartAngle="-120" EndAngle="{Binding EndAngle}" Stretch="None" StrokeThickness="18"
                StrokeDashArray=".25" Stroke="Turquoise" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0,1.4" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="109,126,0,0" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,126,0,85.4" Foreground="White"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="m/s" Width="80" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2"/>


</Grid>
```

This is what it looks like when I run it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2vjk.png)
Can anybody give  me a clue?

Comment: I don't see your control being cut off... Can you mark what is the problem on the screenshot?

Comment: Show the code of `ed:Arc` please.

Comment: I aadded the picture but It is unlikely to be published because I still have not enough reputation.

Comment: @Iron that's all the code I have ed:Arc is taken from Microsoft.Extensions.Drawing.Shapes

Comment: Which dll is `Microsoft.Extensions.Drawing.Shapes` from?

Comment: @Iron Microsoft.Expression.Drawing -Version 3.0.0

Comment: How about the `XAML` that contains the `UserControl`?

Comment: @Iron. Just what I published

Comment: Show the `XAML` code where use the `UserControl`. Something must be wrong while using it.

Comment: Ok I found a work around. I drag the usercontrol directly to the form without a panel and I oversize it, then I need to adapt the proportions. Not really what it should be.